# MalformedInputException in Stream<String> handling

Tags: java, character-encoding, java-8, java-stream

This code seems to be returning a `java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1` error and for the life of me I can't figure out why.

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))
            .forEachOrdered(m -> hashmap.put(LocalDateTime.MIN, m));
```

hashmap is a `HashMap<LocalDateTime, String>`

Full stack error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.io.BufferedReader$1.hasNext(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEachOrdered(Unknown Source)
    at FileHandler.inputSavedDonations(FileHandler.java:92)
    at StreamHelper.main(StreamHelper.java:36)
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Line 92 is `.forEachOrdered(m -> hashmap.put(LocalDateTime.MIN, m));`

`fileName` declaration: `private static String fileName = "file";`

Comment: Please provide a full stack trace and  the value of `fileName`. Then explain  what content is in that file.

Comment: It could be a charset issue. Use `Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName), UTF_8)` or whatever your file encoding is instead.

Comment: Try reducing the input as far as you can (e.g. binarily) to localise the error. If you still do not understand, post the minimal input.

Comment: @Sotirios I've edited it to add the full stack trace and value of fileName

Comment: @assylias, you were right it was reading it in UTF-8 by default when the file was ANSI. Thanks!